# How long does the operation take rfe in R?

Tags: r, rfe

I wrote this code

```
library(caret)

set.seed(100)
options(warn=-1)

subsets <- c(1:5, 10, 15, 18)

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,
                   method = "repeatedcv",
                   repeats = 5,
                   verbose = FALSE)

lmProfile <- rfe(x=train_clean[trainIndex,], y=train_clean_price$SalePrice[trainIndex],
                 sizes = subsets,
                 rfeControl = ctrl)
```

train_clean conteins 80 variables and 1200 lines.
this has been going on for 30 minutes
How to find out how long will the code take to execute?

Answer (score 1):

First, some guidelines when it comes to figuring out  where or why R code takes time to execute.
Read up on `Rprof` , the profiling tool in the `utils` package.  That will show you exactly how much time each call (function) is taking.
Then, You could try using the package `microbenchmark` .

But last, and probably most important, when you find yourself waiting forever for completion,  kill the process and start again with the smallest possible subset of your input data.  For example, try setting up `mini_train <- train_clean[1:5,]` and see what happens... or even  `mini_train <- train_clean[1:5,1:20]`  .  Side note: I'm assuming your "80 variables and 1200 lines" means it's a 1200-by-80 data array.